# git submodules init on werker

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, wercker

I have a problem with submodules too. I can not execute `git submodule init`
I get an error: `Host key verification failed.` I took an example from a documentation page.
I can not understend, how to use ssh keys for getting git repositories from bitbucket.org.
As far as I understood I need to set a var name of my ssh key and fingerprint of bitbucket.
Below code of my pipline:

```
- script:
  name: install git
  code: |
      apt-get update
      apt-get install git -y
- add-ssh-key:
    keyname: MYPACKAGE_KEY
    host: bitbucket.org

- add-to-known_hosts:
    hostname: bitbucket.org
    fingerprint: 3f:d3:c5:17:23:3c:cd:f5:2d:17:76:06:93:7e:ee:97:42:21:14:aa
- script:
    name: initialize git submodules
    code: |
        git submodule update --init --recursive
```

`MYPACKAGE_KEY` - is a name of var ssh key it exist and I put ssh key to bitbucket
where is mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

Initially my workaround was to remove the fingerprint from the add-to-known_hosts step, which worked, but warned that it was not secure.

Shortly after that I found [this bitbucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html), which listed a different fingerprint. Using the rsa md5 listed in that documentation worked for me:

```
- add-to-known_hosts:
    hostname: bitbucket.org
    fingerprint: 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
```